# What does the red icon (lock? Bell?) mean in Trello?

Tags: trello

I've tried hovering for a tooltip. None.
If I open that Card and go back and refresh, the red icon is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That icon indicates that the board is a private board.

[image: Board Permission Settings]